# How does a legitmate administrator get a user's password in ActiveDirectory?

Tags: windows, active-directory, passwords, encryption

If a password is stored with reversable encryption in Active Directory, how does an administrator/developer extract and decrypt this password?

Specifically, I'm referring to [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784581(WS.10).aspx) setting.

Comment: This question belongs on serverfault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Dirk's answer is correct, the RevDump tool only works on Windows Server 2003, as newer versions of Windows store the reversibly encrypted passwords in a [different way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679920(v=vs.85).aspx). Therefore I have created a new [tool](https://www.dsinternals.com/en/retrieving-active-directory-passwords-remotely/) that supports Windows Server 2008+.

Simplest usage example:

```
Get-ADReplAccount -SamAccountName April -Domain Adatum -Server LON-DC1
```

Sample output (partial):

```
DistinguishedName: CN=April Reagan,OU=IT,DC=Adatum,DC=com
Sid: S-1-5-21-3180365339-800773672-3767752645-1375
SamAccountName: April
SamAccountType: User
NTHash: 92937945b518814341de3f726500d4ff
SupplementalCredentials:
  ClearText: Pa$$w0rd
```

Answer (score 4):

The following series of blog posts explains some details:

> **[Passwords stored using reversible encryption: how it works (part 1)](http://blog.teusink.net/2009/08/passwords-stored-using-reversible.html)**
>
> **[Passwords stored using reversible encryption: how it works (part 2)](http://blog.teusink.net/2009/08/passwords-stored-using-reversible_26.html)**

The author of this blog, Niels Teusink, also made the source code of his tool **[RevDump](http://blog.teusink.net/2009/08/revdump-v02-release_15.html)** available for download.

It goes without saying that reversible encryption should not be used globally and only in very exceptional cases.