# Sync AD user's password with mysql database

Tags: mysql, powershell, active-directory

I need to create a web application who use user's information from AD. I need to create script who sync AD and mysql database (I can connect directly cause AD and web server are in 2 different domain). I think about use trigger with event code which execute powershell script, I find all codes I need but I don't have any knowledge in this domain.

I looked how I can get the password hash and which algorithme it use, but I didn't find anything expect it looks impossible cause it's write only due to security reason. The informations I get are from 2013, is it still impossible ?

Thanks in advance,
MYT.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you'd like to copy Windows passwords into MySql, so that users can use the same credentials to both systems. This is a Bad Idea. The proper way would be using integrated authentication, but that requires a [commercial version](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/windows-pluggable-authentication.html) of MySql

Comment: I can't buy a commercial version, is there an other way to get the password hash ?

Comment: A Windows' password hash is not intended to be exportable. That's by design to make password cracking harder. There are ways around, but those require deep knowledge about AD and system security. It's unfortunately one of those "if you have to ask..." topics.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does a legitmate administrator get a user's password in ActiveDirectory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727181/how-does-a-legitmate-administrator-get-a-users-password-in-activedirectory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been asked on here before: [Get AD User Password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727181/how-does-a-legitmate-administrator-get-a-users-password-in-activedirectory)

You first need to create a GPO that allows passwords to be stored using reversible encryption then you can use a PowerShell command: `Get-ADReplAccount -SamAccountName USER_NAME -Domain DOMAIN_NAME -Server SERVER_NAME`

This is a horrible idea and very insecure.

You could authenticate to that domain from another domain as well which would be a lot more secure.

Comment: In your link he ask for decrypt password, I don't need to do it cause I will test 2 hashs. The only problem is that the hash will be exported :c
I looked for make a dmz and comunicate with the machine into, but I don't really know how to do it, so I prefer to do a sync which make me save time

Comment: Your original question didn't say 'hash'. You wanted to sync password... If you want to compare hash, then look at https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/318231-extract-password-hashes-from-ad-users-in-a-single-ou